# How can I test `onKeyDown` prop in React with @testing-library/user-event version 14?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am creating a list of menu items using React. I want to test that when a user clicks or presses enter on an item, the `onSelect` prop is called.

Here is a simplified version of my component:

```
import React from "react";

export const Item = ({ children, onSelect }) => {
  const onKeyDown = ({ keyCode }) => keyCode === 13 && onSelect();
  return (
    <div onClick={onSelect} onKeyDown={onKeyDown} tabIndex={0}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is my test:

```js
describe("Item", () => {
    it("calls onSelect when user clicks on the item or presses Enter", async () => {
      const user = userEvent.setup()
      const onSelect = jest.fn();
      const children = "Settings";
      render(<Item onSelect={onSelect}>{children}</Item>);

      const item = screen.getByText(children);
      await user.click(item);
      expect(onSelect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

      await user.pointer({target: item, keys: '[Enter]'})
      expect(onSelect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
  });
```

When running the tests I get the following output:

```
Item › calls onSelect when user clicks on the item or presses Enter

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 2
    Received number of calls: 1

      48 |
      49 |       await user.pointer({target: item, keys: '[Enter]'})
    > 50 |       expect(onSelect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
         |                        ^
      51 |     });
      52 |   });
      53 |
```

How can I test that `onSelect` was called when the user presses Enter on the item component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/keyboard

> The `keyboard` API allows to simulate interactions with a keyboard. It accepts a `string` describing the key actions.

```js
await user.keyboard('[Enter]')
```

`KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated.
Therefore we don't support it and encourage you to update your implementation to use non-deprecated features like `KeyboardEvent.key` or `KeyboardEvent.code`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-snyder-gurptu?file=/src/Item.test.js

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events)

```
fireEvent.keyDown(domNode, {key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter', charCode: 13})

fireEvent.keyDown(domNode, {key: 'A', code: 'KeyA'})
```

Comment: Is this still correct in `@testing-library/user-event@14.0`?

Comment: I was able to get the test working with 
`fireEvent.keyDown(item, { keyCode: 13 });`